# Is there any way I could increase the damage on my spells in Skyrim?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

My character is a spellsword and her spell damage is just so  low it irritates me and makes me regret ever making her a spellsword. An example I can mention is when I wield a sword on my right hand and a frosbite spell on my left. Now I can go around slashing people's heads off and keep freezing them so they can't get close.

I also heard you could increase the damage on the spell (e.g. frostbite) if you equip it on both hands and click both mouse buttons and your character uses both hands to cast the spell. What I mean here is I want to increase the damage of her spells by the numbers, like if the damage is 150 I want it to be 350 or higher.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are only two ways to improve spell damage:

- Get a better spell
- Get [Augmented Element](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Destruction#Augmented_Flames) Destruction Magic Perks

Indirectly, you can improve your spell damage by lowering your spell cost via Enchanting.  This lets you do more damage before you run out of Magika.

Also, the [Impact Perk](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Destruction#Impact) does not do more damage, but it staggers everything you hit, even dragons, allowing you to kill without retaliation.  It works very well with Fire/Lightning AoE spells.  Less so with Ice due to lower projectile speed.  Unfortunately this perk works only with Dual Casting, so you will need both hands.

Comment: It might be worth mentioning that it is quite possible to reduce spell costs all the way to zero for any given school, with good enough enchanting.  Combining this with expert level spells and the augmented element perks is quite effective.

Comment: Sadly the real bonus to making spell cost zero is that it also affects enchanting charge use.  I'll honestly rather use an enchanted weapon at that point than cast spells :)

Comment: Really?  Which school do I need to fortify?  I never noticed anything like that before.

Comment: Going to move the conversation to http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/31076/skyrim-enchanting

Comment: Kevin most weapon enchants are considered Destruction effects, so to use those weapons without depleting charge you would need a set of Fortify Destruction gear. For Soul Trap, Banish or Fiery Soul Trap, you need Conjuration gear. For Paralysis, you need Alteration gear. For Fear, you need Illusion gear. For Turn Undead, you Restoration gear. If your weapon double enchanted, you need gear for the more costly of the two enchants. See this page: https://en.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Enchanting_Effects#Weapon_Effects for more info. You can sort Weapon enchants by base charge.